# Counterexample or proof that a certain subset in a topological group is closed

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, topological-groups

We consider a Hausdorff topological group $G$ acting on a topological space $X$ [*action* simply means a continuous map $G\times X\rightarrow X$ verifying $(gh)(x)=g(h(x))$, and $1(x)=x$].

The set $H=\{g\in G : \forall x\in X, g(x)=x\}$ is a normal subgroup of G. For example, it is closed if singletons are closed in $X$ .

**I would like to find a Hausdorff topological group $\mathbf{G}$ and a topological space $\mathbf{X}$ such that $\mathbf{H}$ is not closed.**

Note: If we do not require $G$ to be Hausdorff there is a plethora of counterexamples.

Comment: I am assuming that the space $X$ is  $T1$ (i.e. points are closed).  Consider the orbit map $G\rightarrow X$ taking $g\mapsto gx$. If the action is continuous then this maps is continuous. Then $H$ is the preimage of $x$ which is closed. Am I missing something?

Comment: Of course, if singletons are closed in $X$ then $H$ is closed. But that is not what I am asking is it? In any case I clarified the post above.

Comment: Okay thanks for the clarification. If you take $G= \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ and $H = \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ inside $G$. The $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. Take $X= G/H$ with left $G$ action. Then $H$ is not a closed subgroup of $G$ but it is the stabilizer of a point $e.H$.

Comment: Isn't that an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $G$ be a Hausdorff topological group.
Let $N$ be a non-closed normal subgroup of $G$.
Let $X = G/N$.
$G$ acts on $X$.
Let $g$ be an element of $G$.
We denote by $G_g$ the set $\{h \in G |\ hgN = gN\}$.
Then $G_g = gNg^{-1} = N$.
Hence $H = \{g\in G : \forall x\in X, g(x)=x\} = \bigcap \{G_g |\ \forall g \in G\} = N$.
Hence $H$ is not closed.

For example, let $G = \mathbb{R}$ and $N = \mathbb{Q}$.